# Can't access files in a subdirectory using Apache server

Tags: apache2, wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf

I have an Apache 2.2.21 server installed on my Windows 7 machine.
My site is up and my scripts from `/scripts` subdirectory are working but when I try to load icons from `/icons` I get a 403 forbidden error.
I've already added this to my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/icons/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Still no effect. So the question is: how can I access files in my `/icons` subfolder?

P.S.: Using `/images` subdirectory worked out just fine but the question still remains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out that `/icons/` was included as an alias for some other directory. For me, configuration file was located at:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.21\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf
```

I had to comment out this line:

```
Alias /icons/ "c:/Apache22/icons/"
```

Comment: Same! I renamed my directory to `images` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Windows permissions on the `/icons` directory, and made sure that the Apache user can read that directory? Is there possibly an `.htaccess` file in the picture?

Edit: Okay, so it's not permissions. My next guess is this: your config above says "everyone is forbidden access except when they're coming from 127.0.0.1".  But you're on Windows 7.  Windows 7 tries to be helpful and modern - and often tries accessing via IPv6 first.  So you might show up as coming from ::1, which is probably failing to match 127.0.0.1.  Try turning off IPv6 or adding an `Allow from ::1` directive.

Comment: Yes, Windows permissions are all the same.

Comment: I tried it - no luck. `httpd.conf` looks like totally unresponsive to my changes. Again, subfolders like `/scripts` and `/images` are available, so I think it should be a list of them somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if your httpd.conf doesn't do anyhting you should restart apache. Any changes done to documents have to be restarted so Apache can "Refresh".

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/icons/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

- So above this is your code. It basically says in line 4 that Apache should deny connection from all incoming connections connections to the /icons/folder.
- Also on line 5 it says to allow incoming connections from only 127.0.0.1 or localhost. So basically the server has access to it!
- If changing it doesn't work you should look in .htaccess.  Another option is just to copy the Code from a folder that works and paste it and just change the paste from EX: 
  "C:/WAMP/www/images/" to "C:/WAMP/www/icons".

Answer (score 0):

In Linux OS and if you use Apache, you have to change the default Apache configuration and edit this file located here

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf
```

In this file, you have to comment by putting `#` before this line

```
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
```

After changing the configuration, I had to restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And now if you check it, It should work properly.