# WAMP Can't have a folder named 'icons'

Tags: wamp

I'm having some problem with wamp.

I can't seem to have an folder called `icons`. This is where I keep all my icons used on the site. The problem is all my icons are not showing up. If I rename it to something else it works. But I can't seem to have a folder called icons for some reason. I've tried deleting it and made a new folder called icons but it just wont let me.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /icons/ on this server.
```

Why do I get this permission access error?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess files around? Is there something in the alias directory in wamp root? Is there something in your httpd.conf file? Do you have any virtual hosts setup?

Comment: I haven't changed a thing. I recently installed WAMP. No I have zero htaccess files, no virtual hosts

Comment: It won't let you delete the folder and create a new one or you are able to do that and still are denied access through your browser?

Comment: and i have never "chmoded" the directory i dont even know how to

Comment: I can delete it and rename it, if i rename it to for example, icons2 i can access it in the browser. i have tried deleting it and creating a new but its the same

Comment: Funny how naming it ICONS work, or just making one letter uppercase

Comment: You could try doing a file search on your wamp directory looking for 'icons' - there has got to be a rule somewhere causing this. Changing the case is the same as changing the name as far as apache is concerned. If it were me, I'd just pick a different name - its not worth the fight. This question covers the same issue, though it is also unresolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467690/cant-access-files-in-a-subdirectory-using-apache-server You might also look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/431832/why-am-i-getting-network-error-403-forbidden-in-firebug-for-files-i-am-not-tryi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That second link I posted explains the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/431832/why-am-i-getting-network-error-403-forbidden-in-firebug-for-files-i-am-not-tryi

Looks like you can disable `Options Indexes` or edit the alias in `\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf` as shown in the second answer.