# Apache2 does not show .png images

Tags: php, apache2, virtual-machine, png

I just started migrating my code to the google cloud. The server runs Ubuntu but does not display my images (.png).

```
http://example.com/icons/logo.png
```

When I open the console and open the link address directly I receive a 404 not found; but when I just go to `http://example.com/icons``I receive a 403 Forbidden message.

Could it be the case that some permissions for the folder/images are not set correctly? How can display my images?

Comment: It's often helpful to open your browser devtools and look at the Network tab when troubleshooting this sort of problem.

Comment: I know, but it only opens a default 404 no found page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have a similar issue - I have found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467690/cant-access-files-in-a-subdirectory-using-apache-server) and changing the folder name from "icons/" to "images/" resoled the problem, the question of why this happens still remains...